# Link multiple times to a dimension

Tags: iccube

I would like to link multiple times to the same dimension without making a copy of the dimension. I understand that other products have such a feature (role-playing dimensions) but I can't find such functionality in icCube.

Is it really not possible in icCube?

Comment: It's not yet possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the time being you can't link multiple time the same dimension in a measure group. So, you've to copy your dimension (you've a button for doing this in the UI).

Is this a problem ?